# What equations so I can model a "bouncing particle"?

Tags: kinematics, simulations

What equations so I can model a "bouncing particle"?

I've initially started with just $$f(x,y)=(x,\text{abs}(\sin(x)))$$

But I'm interested in doing gravity and speed changes and stuff. So how to proceed?

Some other equations perhaps?

Comment: Do you how a particle moves under gravity?

Comment: @G.Smith I know that it's speed increases $9.81$ m/s per second. But not sure if that's all.

Comment: That's right! So state some initial condition, what is the initial position and velocity of the particle? And then ask yourself what should be the trajectory given that the speed along the x-axis doesn't changes (if one neglects air resistance) while on the y-axis you have the acceleration of 9,81 m/s^2. Only after this you can begin to think about the "buoncing" part.

Comment: Your profile says that you are interested in modeling using differential equations. Can you write the differential equations for a trajectory under gravity without a bounce?

Comment: @FabioDiNocera But is the model based on trigonometric functions or something else? That's what confuses me. That I don't know if there's something more sophisticated than $a\sin(bx)$.

Comment: Surely $a \sin(bx)$ is not the right answer, you can see convince yourself in two ways: watching a bouncing object or seeing that second derivative of the y coordinate is not a constant. @G.Smith gave a nice hint, I reccomend you follow it.

Comment: @FabioDiNocera Well, $a \sin(bx)$ is one type of bouncing particle? But I wonder if the one to look for is: https://www.toptal.com/game/video-game-physics-part-i-an-introduction-to-rigid-body-dynamics

Comment: @mavavilj That's not how a particle would move in a uniform gravitational field. In a uniform gravitational field, the particle undergoes constant acceleration in the air (so position vs time is a quadratic function), and reverses its velocity upon collision with the floor (assuming ideal collisions. If not, the object's velocity after hitting the floor is reversed and slightly smaller).

Comment: The link you have given follows a totally different approach, from what you said in the question you are trying to write the trajectory from the start, while the author of that articles calculates the forces on the object at every frame and updates position and velocity according to these. I don't think this is what you wanted to do. 
By the way I don't  understand what you mean by "a type of bouncing particle". The way something bounces depends on the forces that act on it, and I assumed you were taking the case of a constant acceleration.

Comment: @FabioDiNocera I can take any approach, e.g. the one in that link. I just want to understand how to create "tunable" particle motion.

Comment: Are you looking for physically realistic particle motions, or artistically satisfying ones?  The latter may be better handled by GameDev.SE rather than Physics.SE.